# SharedElementTransition and ContentTransition delayed timing

Tags: android, transition, shared-element-transition

If I have two `Activities` A and B, both have a shared `ImageView`, I would like to have the following transitions play out :

When going from `Activity` A to B, I want to start the `SharedElementTransition` then once that finishes, start the `ContentTransition` of `Activity` B.

When going from `Activity` B back to A, I want to start the `ContentTransition` of `Activity` B then once that finishes, start the `SharedElementTransition` that goes back to `Activity` A

How do you set this delayed timing of `Transitions`?
I am guessing you need some kind of Callback Listeners but am just not sure which ones﻿ to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can leverage a couple of different components depending on your needs and what makes the most sense for you in this particular situation.

Firstly, you will need to leverage [SharedElementCallback](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/app/SharedElementCallback.html)

Using a shared element callback, you'll be able to determine when a shared element transition is complete (among other things). This would be the perfect place to perform another transition, as you referred to as a 'Content Transition'. So after activity B's shared element transition is detected as finished, run content transition.

Conversely, running a transition before a shared element transition is started will be a bit trickier. For this, you would have to add a start delay to the shared element transition.  One way to accomplish this would be something like :

```
getWindow().getSharedElementReenterTransition().setDuration(500);
```

Transitions can also be defined in XML.

Secondly, you should read up on

`onEnterAnimationComplete()`

which is part of AppCompatActivity.  You can override this function in Activity A. This callback is invoked when the Enter Transition for the activity is complete.  This is not the same as the shared element transition.  This, by default is the fade out / fade in that happens to the activities, excluding the views that are involved in the shared element transition.

So, in theory, you could:

1. set a start delay to the reenter shared element transition
2. detect when Activity A's Enter transition is complete and run a custom 'content transition'

if you're timings (start delay's and animation durations) are correct, this will work.

Shared Element Transitions come with a pretty steep learning curve at first because there are some many moving parts, no pun intended. I recommend [this read](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2014/12/activity-fragment-transitions-in-android-lollipop-part1.html) as a starting point.

You should also read up on the built in Activity Transitions such as `Explode()`, `Slide()`, and `Fade()`

They can be leveraged as 'Content Transitions' in tandem with your shared elements transitions to create some pretty nifty stuff.

Answer (score 0):

There are no callbacks for this.  And there is no straight forward way to do it. 
Sorry.

Comment: do you have any explanation why it is not straightforward?  Also what are app devs doing to pull this off.  They must be doing something.

Comment: Do you have an example off an app doing  that?

Comment: I figured out what was wrong.  I added startDelay and duration to some of the transitions which was throwing off all of the timing.  When used appropriately those two attributes will set up the timing that you need.  Also i was using windowExitTransition instead of windowReturnTransition which threw things off.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution... I only stated that you can't know or have a callback for when an animation is done.